# Is there a "hard / soft nofile" equivalent in Windows?

Tags: windows

I'm installing on my Win 10 machine a development environment for a project by following a tutorial made for Linux, and one of the steps is to set soft nofile 4096 and hard nofile 65572. I know what these do in Linux, but I'm wondering if there's a Windows equivalent or if I should just skip that step altogether.

Comment: its my understanding that nofile defines the max number of files a user may have open. In windows this is represented by handles ('cause in windows not everything is a file). check this (perhaps dated) exploration of handle limits in windows: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/markrussinovich/2009/09/29/pushing-the-limits-of-windows-handles/ Personally, I think you can skip it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(For people not familiar with Linux: those settings represent the **n**umber of **o**pen **file**s that a non-root process can have.)

No, Windows has [effectively no limit](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20081009-00/?p=20613) on the number of handles (and therefore files) that a user or process can have open at once. As mentioned in [the article](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/markrussinovich/2009/09/29/pushing-the-limits-of-windows-handles/) linked by Frank Thomas in the comments, each process can have up to 16,777,216 handles open because that's the maximum allowed number of entries in a handle table, but that's far more than any application should ever need. In practice, you can't get there because you need memory for other things.

Note that the "maximum open files per session" limit shown by `net config server` only applies to clients accessing files from network shares. The `net` command [does not provide](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490700.aspx) a way to change that limit.